# Why does $\sin{x} = \frac{1}{2}$ have two solutions but $\arcsin{\frac{1}{2}}$ has one solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Can anyone help me understand why $\sin{x} = \frac{1}{2}$ have two solutions but $\arcsin{\frac{1}{2}}$ has one solution?

Aren't they equivalent?

Comment: Actually the first equation has infinite solutions because sine is periodic and 1/2 lies between -1 and 1 inclusive. Arcsine, on the other hand, has a restricted domain and range that leave a lone solution in order to satisfy the definition of a function, hence the disparity

Comment: The function $\phi=\arcsin{\tfrac{1}{2}}$ has actually these two solutions for $\phi$:
$\phi_1=\pi/6$ and $\phi_2=5\pi/6$, hence $\arcsin{\tfrac{1}{2}}$ has two solutions, and as well infinite if we sum $2\pi n$ with $n$ an integer.

Comment: $\arcsin\frac{1}{2}$ has no "solutions", $\arcsin\frac{1}{2}$ is just a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the same reason that
$$
x^2 = 1
$$
has two solutions ($x = 1$ and $x = -1$) but $\sqrt{1}$ has only one solution (the square root of $1$ is $1$, not $-1$.)

The weird thing about $\arcsin y$ is that it does NOT give you all possible values $x$ such that $\sin x = y$. It cannot do that, because we want it to be a function, in other words, for every input there is only exactly one output. So if I put in $\frac12$ for $y$ and look at $\arcsin \frac12$, $\arcsin$ can only give me one output, not multiple outputs. So $\arcsin$ gives me back $\frac{\pi}{6}$, even though there are infinitely other many values of $x$ that satisfy the equation. $\arcsin$ just gives me ONE of them.

In summary, there are infinitely many $x$ such that $\sin x = \frac12$, but $\arcsin$ is a function so it can only give one of them back. $\arcsin \frac12$ is therefore just A solution to the equation, not ALL solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Since the sine function is not one-to-one, the sine function does not have an inverse. Arcsine (or "Inverse sine"), is actually the inverse of the restricted sine function from $-\frac{\pi}2$ (radians) to $\frac{\pi}2$ (radians). Therefore, the arcsine of $\frac{1}2$ only has on solution on that particular interval, but since the (regular) sine function is periodic, the first equation you asked about has not only 2 solutions, but infinate solutions.